# How to align an expression in an amsmath environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, amsmath

If I write

```
\begin{align} 
A = <long string of variables> \\
=& <another long string of variables>
\end{align}
```

This works and aligns the equal signs and makes the total block of two-lines centered.

Now I want to remove the "A =" part, and simply assert that `<long string of variables>` is equal to `<another long string of variables>`. However, every version of this I write makes the left alignment of the second line to the left of the first, since `<another long string of variables>` is even longer.

How can I force the second line to shift over to the right so that the equal sign lies underneath the first line, somewhat? I've tried `\hspace` and a million alignment tricks but none of them have worked. I'd also be fine if I could just left-align the first line and right-align the second line!

Comment: Your code doesn't align the `=` sign on whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
 \begin{align*}
 & \phantom{{}={}}\text{long string of variables}\\
& = \text{another long string of variables}
  \end{align*}
```

or this (as suggested by @daleif):

```
\begin{align*}
&\text{long string of variables}\\
 ={} & \text{another long string of variables}
  \end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Less to write if you use `&` in the first row and `={} & ` on the second.

Comment: @daleif: You're right, if there are no other lines with alignment. I've updated my answer. Thanks!